# Object Oriented programming and paths

Tags: oop, object, path

This may sound like a stupid question but.. Let a path be object.field. If we have 2 paths object1.field1 == object2.field2. (object1.field1 and object2.field2 evaluates to the same object). What does this tell us about object1, object2, field1 and field2 ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets first set up an example

```
Class Person:
  property age

John = New Person()
John.age = 30

Jane = New Person()
Jane.age = 30
```

If by `object1.field1 = object2.field2` you mean `object1.field1` equals `object2.field2` then it tells us that both object1 (`John`) and objact2 (`Jane`) have the same field (`30`). Of course if the field is an object (like a sibling) then it also tells us that they share that field.

Comment: Actually it says object1.field1 and object2.field2 evaluates to the same object but that confuses me a little bit.. (I think the field values can only be a pointer or an object). = should have been == I am sorry.

Comment: so you mean `John.age == jane.height`? It depends on the language and the types of the fields. If they are literals, then that means they have the same value like if John's age is 30 and Jane is 30 inches tall. If it's C, it *can* mean that both fields point to the same memory location.

Comment: Yeah its a general C for class so I think it may be the case that they point to the same memory location as you said.

Comment: Think of it as both of them having the same mother ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the language and the implementation of the `path` object.  But minimally the assignment, `object1.field1 = object2.field2`, should make the two fields equivalent, `object1.field1 == object2.field2`.